# How to inspect running bash script from outside (i.e. without running it in a dedicated shell)

Tags: bash, shell, sh, signals, callstack

Imagine an arbitrary *already running* shell script (`bash`, `sh`, ..) that gets stuck in an endless loop and you want to 'look into it' (i.e. get a stack trace or current position in the script) to get an idea of what's going on.

In *Python* when I encounter strange behavior (in terms of CPU usage, endless loops, etc), my typical approach is to make the script allow me to 'look into it' while it's running. E.g. I would extend a given script, say

```py
def fib(n):
    return 0 if n == 0 else 1 if n < 3 else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

print(fib(38))  # might run long
```

to handle some signal, e.g. `SIGPOLL` like this:

```py
import signal, traceback, os

def fib(n):
    return 0 if n == 0 else 1 if n < 3 else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

signal.signal(signal.SIGPOLL, lambda sig, frame: print(
    "\n".join(traceback.format_stack(frame))))
print(f"This might take long - run `kill -{signal.SIGPOLL} {os.getpid()}` to look into stack")

print(fib(38))  # might run long
```

Now I can just run `kill -SIGPOLL <PID>` from another terminal whenever I find this script to run surprisingly long. I still need to run it in a dedicated terminal first to see the output, but I could easily modify the code to write to a file or similar.

Is this possible for `bash`/`sh`, too? Maybe even built in?

Best would be if I didn't even have to modify the script in the first place, but if there is any way apart from executing it in an extra shell with `strace` or `-x` being set, I'd take it :)

Here is what I sometimes use - it helps me in some situations but does not give me detailed information about the code being executed like line numbers, call stack etc, and the script has to be run in an extra terminal in order to see the output:

```sh
function toggle_tracing {
    if [ -z "$TRACE_ENABLED" ]; then
        TRACE_ENABLED=1
        set -x
    else
        unset TRACE_ENABLED
        set +x
    fi
}

trap toggle_tracing USR1
echo "run 'kill -SIGUSR1 $BASHPID' to activate tracing"

# do something really time consuming
while true; do
    find ~ > /dev/null
done
```

For this approach to work I have to prepare advance (the script needs to be modified and run in a dedicated terminal or tmux session), which is bad to investigate on unexpected and infrequently occurring incidents.

You could also run `strace -p <PID>`, which has the advantage of not being limited to (shell-)scripts, but since you only get system IO you have to be lucky *and* know the executable very well to guess it's inner state.

Comment: Your solution seems broken because receiving a signal won't execute the trap until the current (executing) command finish

Comment: yes, it's definitively broken - the worst thing is, that I would have to run in a terminal I can monitor in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that *somehow* meets my requirements is to combine setting `-x` on demand *and* `strace`, since the traces will be written to `STDERR` which I can trace from outside.

Preparation: modify the script that *might* get stuck in the future to run the following code on startup:

```
function toggle_tracing {
    if [ -z "$TRACE_ENABLED" ]; then
        TRACE_ENABLED=1
        set -x
    else
        unset TRACE_ENABLED
        set +x
    fi
}

trap toggle_tracing USR1
echo "run 'kill -SIGUSR1 $BASHPID' to activate tracing"
```

When you now catch the process to eat up your CPU for hours you set it into trace mode by sending a signal and start monitoring it using strace

```sh
# sudo might not be necessary
sudo kill -SIGUSR1 <PID>
sudo strace -p <PID> 2>&1 | grep "write(2, \""
```

which will result in the commands being printed to the terminal you ran `strace` in

```
write(2, "+ true\n", 7)                 = 7
write(2, "+ find /home/itsme\n", 20)   = 20
write(2, "+ true\n", 7)                 = 7
write(2, "+ find /home/itsme\n", 20)   = 20
write(2, "+ true\n", 7)                 = 7
write(2, "+ find /home/itsme\n", 20)   = 20
write(2, "+ true\n", 7)                 = 7
write(2, "+ find /home/itsme\n", 20)   = 20
write(2, "+ true\n", 7)                 = 7
write(2, "+ find /home/itsme\n", 20)   = 20
...
```

(still without line numbers, though)

Btw, credits go to a friend of mine who is too lazy to setup their own account.